# Why do my windows process handles stick around forever?

Tags: c, windows, process

I can find process ids on my system that are associated with processes that do not show up in Task Manager, because they terminated long ago, but which also do not go away. To identify them, i use these system calls:

```c
static int
process_is_zombie(DWORD pid)
{
    DWORD exit_value;
    DWORD dwR;
    HANDLE process_handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, pid);
    if (!process_handle)
        return -1; // no handle attached to pid
    int exit_return = GetExitCodeProcess(process_handle, &exit_value);
    if (!exit_return)
        return -1; // GetExitCodeProcess failed, maybe no permission
    if(exit_value != STILL_ACTIVE)
        return 1; // got a handle, but process is definitely dead
    dwR = WaitForSingleObject(process_handle, 0);
    if(dwR == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        return 1; // nope, it's really dead
    if(dwR == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
        return 0; // still alive!
    return -1; // WaitForSingleObject failed, maybe no permission
}
```

On my system task manager shows 170 running processes, but when scanning from pid 0 to pid 700_000 i find over 150_000 of the afore described "zombie" pids. Inspecting the handles of the processes alive on my system using Process Explorer/Task Manager does not show a single process with more than 2600 handles, so none of my live processes seem to keep these zombies around.

From what i could find out, these pids stick around because something still has a handle on them. However what i can't find is information on how i can find out what exactly has handles on these process ids.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Process Explorer can show you what process handles each process has open.  You can download it from Microsoft's web site.  However, it is very unlikely that 150,000 processes exited with an error code of `STILL_ACTIVE` (never mind that there are still handles to them) so I think the problem is that you don't initialize `is_zombie` to zero.

Comment: Process Explorer does not help in this case. Also the code is just a very abbreviated example, and now that I think about it I think I made a mistake on how I abbreviated it. I will have to amend that tomorrow.

Comment: You need to post real, working code that actually demonstrates the problem.  What's wrong with Process Explorer?  You would have to go through the processes one by one, but if a process really has 150k process handles open that would stick out like a sore thumb.  Actually, Task Manager would be the first thing to check; it can show how many handles in total each process has open.

Comment: Yes, I do, but it's 0400 here, so I can't do it immediately. Process Explorer does not help, as none of the processes it shows have anywhere near that amount of handles. (You can configure it also to show a column with handles.)

Comment: There's no rush.  But if Process Explorer is not showing the handles in question, then they don't exist.  Either your code isn't working right, or something in kernel mode is keeping the process objects from being tidied up.  One possibility: I don't know whether OpenProcess() necessarily works as expected when passed a process ID that doesn't exist.  It might be that you're getting a handle to the current process, or a random process, or a dummy handle of some kind.  Try calling GetProcessId() and check whether the pid returned matches the original one or not.

Comment: You could also try `GetModuleFileNameEx` to determine the executable filename.  I'm not sure whether that works on exited processes or not, but it would be easy enough to check.

Comment: As i said, i'd made a mistake in my code. I've inserted the correct version now, with the problematic pids being those where the code returns 1. I'll try the `GetProcessId` thing today. `GetModuleFileNameEx` won't be particularly helpful, as i already know that almost every process i close on my system becomes a zombie.

Comment: OK, that code seems to be working as intended.  On my machine (Windows 7, 64-bit, program running in 32-bit mode) it returns only a handful of results between 1 and 700,000.  Assuming the problem only occurs on your machine (as opposed to, say, every Windows 8 machine) then Driver Verifier might be able to identify the device driver causing the problem, or you might have to identify it by trial and error.  Anti-virus software would be the most likely culprit.  Another possibility is a rootkit.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. As for stuff like AV software, i don't run that, and in fact have a full kernel debugger dump of all handles on my system: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10190786/processes The dump does include all the zombie processes, but they don't have handle tables and the existing process handles only point at live processes. Rootkit is also unlikely since i've seen this on 4 distinct machines already, distributed across the earth. Trying driver verifier.

Comment: Kernel-mode code can keep an object alive by holding a reference to it without actually creating a handle, see ObReferenceObject and related functions.  Unfortunately if that's what happening I don't know whether Driver Verifier will help.  You might want to look for common factors between the affected machines.

Comment: Yeah, i've been trying to do that. Amazingly it happens even in safe mode. Also, jeeze, with the existence of ObReferenceObject there's a myriad of options.

Comment: Might be worth trying a clean instance of Windows in a virtual machine, e.g., I think Windows already contains all the device drivers needed to run inside Windows Virtual PC, so you could try it out with absolutely no third-party software present.

Comment: I found with some more kd digging that the processes have no handle counts, but have pointer counts, which all literature indicates come from kernel mode software, i.e. drivers: `HandleCount: 0 PointerCount: 74` This answers the question for me. If you like you can slot that in as answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: Done; it might be helpful for future readers if you could edit in a summary of the kd command(s) you used to check the pointer counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways in which process objects (and hence process IDs) can be kept alive.  Firstly, user-mode handles; you eliminated that early on by checking the handle count in Process Explorer and/or Task Manager.  Secondly, kernel-mode handles, which you eliminated with a kernel debugger handle dump.

The last possibility is kernel-mode references (aka "pointers" in kd).  These are created with [ObReferenceObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558678(v=vs.85).aspx) and related functions.

A pointer count of 74 for a long-exited process suggests to me that the reference has been leaked multiple times.  In principle, with kd and Driver Verifier, it might be possible to search for pointers to the object and identify which driver owns the memory containing them.  But it may be more practical to identify the faulty driver by trial-and-error.  Good luck!